# New Java Locale - af_ZA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, internationalization, locale

How can I request the Java developers to add support for my home language Afrikaans - South Africa? Especially to get the correct labels when formatting a date (month names etc.)

Alternatively, is it possible for me to add my own implementation of my home language to my Java-EE project?

Users can dynamically switch between languages and I like Java's support for English, French, German, etc.

English: works great!

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", new Locale("en_US")).format(new Date());
```

Afrikaans: returns English labels too.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", new Locale("af_ZA")).format(new Date());
```

Comment: I found a similar requirement here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743435/how-to-modify-dateformatsymbols-month-values

Answer (score 0):

Check out the method [SimpleDateFormat#setDateFormatSymbols()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#setDateFormatSymbols-java.text.DateFormatSymbols-). There you will find that you can set your completely customized set of localized configuration data. There's also a constructor available to set them at construction time.

For even wider localization support you should check out the extensive documentation on the [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

You can add support for any locale you want with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/services.html

Or you can use ICU4J, much better.

But there is something weird with your code.
Does new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", "af_ZA") even build?
There is no SimpleDateFormat(String, String) constructor.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Mihai

Comment: Well spotted Mihai, thank you. I updated it to use a valid constructor.