# Date Format issue in Android 12 & 13

Tags: java, android, kotlin, date, android-version

I am using `dd-MMM-yyyy` format in `String` format in kotlin in android.
It returns `"01-Sept-2022"` as a result.
I want `"01-Sep-2022"` as result.
This issue shows up in android 12 & 13.

```kotlin
@JvmStatic
fun getCurrentDate(format: String): String {
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format)
    val currentDate = sdf.format(Date())
    return currentDate
}
```

How can I get my desired return value in all versions?

Comment: show us the code of how you are formatting the date

Comment: @JvmStatic
    fun getCurrentDate(format: String): String {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format)
        val currentDate = sdf.format(Date())
        return currentDate
    }

Comment: Which `Locale` is your `Locale.getDefault()`? You can try out different `Locale`s in [`SimpleDateFormate(String, Locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)), maybe one is reliably formatting as desired. The pattern should already be correct.

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Not being an Android developer I don’t know where Android locale data such as abbreviations used in different languages come from. They are likely to reflect what users want, so I wouldn’t worry much. However, if you want to guard against changes in the next version I believe the good solution is using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `appendText` method for specifying the exact abbreviations you want. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52374919/5772882) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57183455/5772882).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @deHaar `SimpleDateFormat` returns the formatted string depending on the `Locale`. Take a look at all locales and you will find the correct form you want. Below I added a snippet where you can easily find it. If you develop this app for the app store or for other public users you shouldn't change the Locale in `SimpleDateFormat` because the user in this region normally knows this format. The `Locale.getDefault` is also influenced by the Android system settings.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val out = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.out)
    out.text = getCurrentDate("dd-MMM-yyyy")
}

fun getCurrentDate(format: String): String {
    var result = ""

    val locales = listOf<Locale>(Locale.CANADA, Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, Locale.CHINA, Locale.CHINESE,
        Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.FRANCE, Locale.FRENCH, Locale.GERMAN, Locale.GERMANY, Locale.ITALIAN,
        Locale.ITALY, Locale.JAPAN, Locale.JAPANESE, Locale.KOREA, Locale.KOREAN, Locale.PRC,
        Locale.ROOT, Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE, Locale.TAIWAN, Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE, Locale.UK, Locale.US)

    locales.forEach {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format, it)
        result += sdf.format(Date()) + "\n"
    }
    return result
}
```

returns

```
04-Sep.-2022
04-sept.-2022
04-9月-2022
04-9月-2022
04-Sep-2022
04-sept.-2022
04-sept.-2022
04-Sept.-2022
04-Sept.-2022
04-set-2022
04-set-2022
04-9月-2022
04-9月-2022
04-9월-2022
04-9월-2022
04-9月-2022
04-Sep-2022
04-9月-2022
04-9月-2022
04-9月-2022
04-Sep-2022
04-Sep-2022
```