# Dynamically creating a regex from a DateFormat

Tags: java, regex, date

I need to detect some stuff within a String that contains, among other things, dates. Now, [parsing dates using regex is a known question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy).

However, the dates in this text are localized. And the app needs to be able to adapt to differently localized dates. Luckily, I can figure out the correct date format for the current locale using `DateFormat.getDateInstance(SHORT, locale)`. I can get a date pattern from that. But how do I turn it into a regex, dynamically?

The regex would not need to do in-depth *validation* of the format (leap years, correct amount of days for a month etc.), I can already be sure that the data is provided in a valid format. The date just needs to be identified (as in, the regex should be able to detect the start and end index of where a date is).

The answers in the linked question all assume the handful of common date formats. But assuming that in this case is a likely cause of getting an edge case that breaks the app in a very non-obvious way. Which is why I'd prefer a dynamically generated regex over a one-fits-all(?) solution.

I can't use `DateFormat.parse(...)`, since I have to actually detect the date first, and can't directly extract it.

Comment: So, as an example, the `GERMANY` pattern is `dd.MM.yy`, so you want that to be a regex like .... what? `\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}`? Or `(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])/Q./E(?:1[0-2]|0[1-9])/Q./E[0-9][0-9]`? Or do you want it to create regex for full month length validation, including leap years? You question is **too broad**.

Comment: @Andreas No need for validation of leap years and such, I just need identification. Will update the question to try and make that more clear.

Comment: I still think that parsing from each position in the string and seeing if it succeeds is easier than first generating a regular expression. The latter won’t be impossible, but complex, since the pattern may contain both letters and digits and constant parts in quotes.

Comment: If you want to pursuit this option, I suggest that [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#getLocalizedDateTimePattern-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.chrono.Chronology-java.util.Locale-) is the direct way to the best starting point. Also `DateFormat` is long outdated and notoriously troublesome, so while it may work OK for this particialr purpose, it’s a good habit to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, instead.

Comment: i didn’t get your last paragraph. What would be wrong with extracting the date from the outset and just catching an exception every time you fail? Also it may help if you show us a couple of examples of how your string may look.

Comment: @OleV.V. The usage of `DateFormat` isn't something I can control - the code that generates the text that needs to be parsed uses it (I can't change that), and doing the same is the best way to ensure I will also end up with the same correct localized format. AFAIK, trial and error with exceptions is also bad practice :P The String actually contains "(date)(data)(date)(data)..." I need to split it into one (date) with one (data) each. Only one date per data, but the data has no consistency. Which means I have to use a pattern that detects a date, then anything until the next date.

Comment: Are those parentheses literal?  Is a date enclosed in `(`…`)`?  If not, are there any delimiters in the input at all?  Seems like searching for those would be far easier than converting a possibly localized DateFormat to a regular expression.

Comment: @VGR The parentheses are not literal. No reliable delimiters apart from the dates.

Comment: I wouldn’t immediately expect `DateFormat` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to give different formats, but this is something that can be checked for every available locale. I foresee another problem if at some point you upgrade from Java 8 to Java 9: the default locale data in those versions are quite different, and you would at least have to tell your Java 9 to use Java’s locale data from Java 8 and earlier. [Learn more here: SimpleDateFormat with German Locale - Java 8 vs Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411064/simpledateformat-with-german-locale-java-8-vs-java-10).

Comment: FWIW, on my Java 1.8.0_131 using default locale data *one* locale gives a different format pattern string from `DateFormat` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`: ja_JP_JP_#u-ca-japanese. In all other locales the value from `((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, loc)).toPattern()` equals the one from `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, loc)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing `getDateInstance(SHORT, locale)`, with emphasis on `Date` and `SHORT`, the patterns are fairly limited, so the following code will do:

```
public static String dateFormatToRegex(Locale locale) {
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
    String fmt = ((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale)).toPattern();
    for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]+|([a-zA-Z])\\1*").matcher(fmt); m.find(); ) {
        String part = m.group();
        if (m.start(1) == -1) { // Not letter(s): Literal text
            regex.append(Pattern.quote(part));
        } else {
            switch (part.charAt(0)) {
                case 'G': // Era designator
                    regex.append("\\p{L}+");
                    break;
                case 'y': // Year
                    regex.append("\\d{1,4}");
                    break;
                case 'M': // Month in year
                    if (part.length() > 2)
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Date format part: " + part);
                    regex.append("(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])");
                    break;
                case 'd': // Day in month
                    regex.append("(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Date format part: " + part);
            }
        }
    }
    return regex.toString();
}
```

To see what regex's you'll get for various locales:

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
Arrays.sort(locales, Comparator.comparing(Locale::toLanguageTag));
Map<String, List<String>> fmtLocales = new TreeMap<>();
for (Locale locale : locales) {
    String fmt = ((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale)).toPattern();
    fmtLocales.computeIfAbsent(fmt, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(locale.toLanguageTag());
}
fmtLocales.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(dateFormatToRegex(Locale.forLanguageTag(v.get(0))) + "   " + v));
```

*Output*

```
\p{L}+\d{1,4}\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])   [ja-JP-u-ca-japanese-x-lvariant-JP]
(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q/\E\d{1,4}   [brx, brx-IN, chr, chr-US, ee, ee-GH, ee-TG, en, en-AS, en-BI, en-GU, en-MH, en-MP, en-PR, en-UM, en-US, en-US-POSIX, en-VI, fil, fil-PH, ks, ks-IN, ug, ug-CN, zu, zu-ZA]
(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q/\E\d{1,4}   [es-PA, es-PR]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q-\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q-\E\d{1,4}   [or, or-IN]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q. \E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q. \E\d{1,4}   [ksh, ksh-DE]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q. \E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q. \E\d{1,4}   [sl, sl-SI]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E\d{1,4}   [fi, fi-FI, he, he-IL, is, is-IS]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E\d{1,4}   [be, be-BY, dsb, dsb-DE, hsb, hsb-DE, sk, sk-SK, sq, sq-AL, sq-MK, sq-XK]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E\d{1,4}\Q.\E   [bs-Cyrl, bs-Cyrl-BA, sr, sr-CS, sr-Cyrl, sr-Cyrl-BA, sr-Cyrl-ME, sr-Cyrl-RS, sr-Cyrl-XK, sr-Latn, sr-Latn-BA, sr-Latn-ME, sr-Latn-RS, sr-Latn-XK, sr-ME, sr-RS]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E\d{1,4}   [tr, tr-CY, tr-TR]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E\d{1,4}\Q 'г'.\E   [bg, bg-BG]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E\d{1,4}   [agq, agq-CM, bas, bas-CM, bm, bm-ML, dje, dje-NE, dua, dua-CM, dyo, dyo-SN, en-HK, en-ZW, ewo, ewo-CM, ff, ff-CM, ff-GN, ff-MR, ff-SN, kab, kab-DZ, kea, kea-CV, khq, khq-ML, ksf, ksf-CM, ln, ln-AO, ln-CD, ln-CF, ln-CG, lo, lo-LA, lu, lu-CD, mfe, mfe-MU, mg, mg-MG, mua, mua-CM, nmg, nmg-CM, rn, rn-BI, seh, seh-MZ, ses, ses-ML, sg, sg-CF, shi, shi-Latn, shi-Latn-MA, shi-MA, shi-Tfng, shi-Tfng-MA, sw-CD, twq, twq-NE, yav, yav-CM, zgh, zgh-MA, zh-HK, zh-Hant-HK, zh-Hant-MO]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E\d{1,4}   [ast, ast-ES, bn, bn-BD, bn-IN, ca, ca-AD, ca-ES, ca-ES-VALENCIA, ca-FR, ca-IT, el, el-CY, el-GR, en-AU, en-SG, es, es-419, es-AR, es-BO, es-BR, es-CR, es-CU, es-DO, es-EA, es-EC, es-ES, es-GQ, es-HN, es-IC, es-NI, es-PH, es-PY, es-SV, es-US, es-UY, es-VE, gu, gu-IN, ha, ha-GH, ha-NE, ha-NG, haw, haw-US, hi, hi-IN, km, km-KH, kn, kn-IN, ml, ml-IN, mr, mr-IN, pa, pa-Guru, pa-Guru-IN, pa-IN, pa-PK, ta, ta-IN, ta-LK, ta-MY, ta-SG, th, th-TH, to, to-TO, ur, ur-IN, ur-PK, zh-Hans-HK, zh-Hans-MO]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E\d{1,4}   [th-TH-u-nu-thai-x-lvariant-TH]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E\d{1,4}   [nus, nus-SS]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E\d{1,4}   [en-NZ, es-CO, es-GT, es-PE, fr-BE, ms, ms-BN, ms-MY, ms-SG, nl-BE]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q-\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q-\E\d{1,4}   [sv-FI]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q-\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q-\E\d{1,4}   [es-CL, fy, fy-NL, my, my-MM, nl, nl-AW, nl-BQ, nl-CW, nl-NL, nl-SR, nl-SX, rm, rm-CH, te, te-IN]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E\d{1,4}   [mk, mk-MK]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E\d{1,4}   [nb, nb-NO, nb-SJ, nn, nn-NO, nn-NO, no, no-NO, pl, pl-PL, ro, ro-MD, ro-RO, tk, tk-TM]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E\d{1,4}\Q.\E   [hr, hr-BA, hr-HR]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E\d{1,4}   [az, az-AZ, az-Cyrl, az-Cyrl-AZ, az-Latn, az-Latn-AZ, cs, cs-CZ, de, de-AT, de-BE, de-CH, de-DE, de-LI, de-LU, et, et-EE, fo, fo-DK, fo-FO, fr-CH, gsw, gsw-CH, gsw-FR, gsw-LI, hy, hy-AM, it-CH, ka, ka-GE, kk, kk-KZ, ky, ky-KG, lb, lb-LU, lv, lv-LV, os, os-GE, os-RU, ru, ru-BY, ru-KG, ru-KZ, ru-MD, ru-RU, ru-UA, uk, uk-UA]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q.\E\d{1,4}\Q.\E   [bs, bs-BA, bs-Latn, bs-Latn-BA]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q \E\d{1,4}   [kkj, kkj-CM]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E\d{1,4}   [am, am-ET, asa, asa-TZ, bem, bem-ZM, bez, bez-TZ, cgg, cgg-UG, da, da-DK, da-GL, dav, dav-KE, ebu, ebu-KE, en-001, en-150, en-AG, en-AI, en-AT, en-BB, en-BM, en-BS, en-CC, en-CH, en-CK, en-CM, en-CX, en-CY, en-DE, en-DG, en-DK, en-DM, en-ER, en-FI, en-FJ, en-FK, en-FM, en-GB, en-GD, en-GG, en-GH, en-GI, en-GM, en-GY, en-IE, en-IL, en-IM, en-IO, en-JE, en-JM, en-KE, en-KI, en-KN, en-KY, en-LC, en-LR, en-LS, en-MG, en-MO, en-MS, en-MT, en-MU, en-MW, en-MY, en-NA, en-NF, en-NG, en-NL, en-NR, en-NU, en-PG, en-PH, en-PK, en-PN, en-PW, en-RW, en-SB, en-SC, en-SD, en-SH, en-SI, en-SL, en-SS, en-SX, en-SZ, en-TC, en-TK, en-TO, en-TT, en-TV, en-TZ, en-UG, en-VC, en-VG, en-VU, en-WS, en-ZM, fr, fr-BF, fr-BI, fr-BJ, fr-BL, fr-CD, fr-CF, fr-CG, fr-CI, fr-CM, fr-DJ, fr-DZ, fr-FR, fr-GA, fr-GF, fr-GN, fr-GP, fr-GQ, fr-HT, fr-KM, fr-LU, fr-MA, fr-MC, fr-MF, fr-MG, fr-ML, fr-MQ, fr-MR, fr-MU, fr-NC, fr-NE, fr-PF, fr-PM, fr-RE, fr-RW, fr-SC, fr-SN, fr-SY, fr-TD, fr-TG, fr-TN, fr-VU, fr-WF, fr-YT, ga, ga-IE, gd, gd-GB, guz, guz-KE, ig, ig-NG, jmc, jmc-TZ, kam, kam-KE, kde, kde-TZ, ki, ki-KE, kln, kln-KE, ksb, ksb-TZ, lag, lag-TZ, lg, lg-UG, luo, luo-KE, luy, luy-KE, mas, mas-KE, mas-TZ, mer, mer-KE, mgh, mgh-MZ, mt, mt-MT, naq, naq-NA, nd, nd-ZW, nyn, nyn-UG, pa-Arab, pa-Arab-PK, qu, qu-BO, qu-EC, qu-PE, rof, rof-TZ, rwk, rwk-TZ, saq, saq-KE, sbp, sbp-TZ, sn, sn-ZW, sw, sw-KE, sw-TZ, sw-UG, teo, teo-KE, teo-UG, tzm, tzm-MA, vai, vai-LR, vai-Latn, vai-Latn-LR, vai-Vaii, vai-Vaii-LR, vi, vi-VN, vun, vun-TZ, xog, xog-UG, yo, yo-BJ, yo-NG]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E\d{1,4}   [cy, cy-GB, en-BE, en-BW, en-BZ, en-IN, es-MX, fur, fur-IT, gl, gl-ES, id, id-ID, it, it-IT, it-SM, nnh, nnh-CM, om, om-ET, om-KE, pt, pt-AO, pt-BR, pt-CH, pt-CV, pt-GQ, pt-GW, pt-LU, pt-MO, pt-MZ, pt-PT, pt-ST, pt-TL, so, so-DJ, so-ET, so-KE, so-SO, ti, ti-ER, ti-ET, uz, uz-AF, uz-Cyrl, uz-Cyrl-UZ, uz-Latn, uz-Latn-UZ, uz-UZ, yi, yi-001, zh-Hans-SG, zh-SG]
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q‏/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q‏/\E\d{1,4}   [ar, ar-001, ar-AE, ar-BH, ar-DJ, ar-DZ, ar-EG, ar-EH, ar-ER, ar-IL, ar-IQ, ar-JO, ar-KM, ar-KW, ar-LB, ar-LY, ar-MA, ar-MR, ar-OM, ar-PS, ar-QA, ar-SA, ar-SD, ar-SO, ar-SS, ar-SY, ar-TD, ar-TN, ar-YE]
\d{1,4}\Q-\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q-\E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])   [af, af-NA, af-ZA, as, as-IN, bo, bo-CN, bo-IN, br, br-FR, ce, ce-RU, ckb, ckb-IQ, ckb-IR, cu, cu-RU, dz, dz-BT, en-CA, en-SE, gv, gv-IM, ii, ii-CN, jgo, jgo-CM, kl, kl-GL, kok, kok-IN, kw, kw-GB, lkt, lkt-US, lrc, lrc-IQ, lrc-IR, lt, lt-LT, mgo, mgo-CM, mn, mn-MN, mzn, mzn-IR, ne, ne-IN, ne-NP, prg, prg-001, se, se-FI, se-NO, se-SE, si, si-LK, smn, smn-FI, sv, sv-AX, sv-SE, und, uz-Arab, uz-Arab-AF, vo, vo-001, wae, wae-CH]
\d{1,4}\Q. \E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q. \E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E   [hu, hu-HU]
\d{1,4}\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])   [fa, fa-AF, fa-IR, ps, ps-AF, yue, yue-HK, zh, zh-CN, zh-Hans, zh-Hans-CN, zh-Hant, zh-Hant-TW, zh-TW]
\d{1,4}\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])   [en-ZA, eu, eu-ES, ja, ja-JP]
\d{1,4}\Q-\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q-\E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])   [eo, eo-001, fr-CA, sr-BA]
\d{1,4}\Q. \E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q. \E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\Q.\E   [ko, ko-KP, ko-KR]
\d{1,4}\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])   [sah, sah-RU]
\d{1,4}\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\Q/\E(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])   [ak, ak-GH, rw, rw-RW]
```

Comment: Tested on my Java 10.0.2. In 435 out of 736 available locales (about 60 %) the generated regex matches dates formatted with the same localized `DateFormat` (I didn’t make the finer distinction into languages alone in my test).

Comment: I think it needs to use `0?` for months and days. For example finland uses `d.M.yyyy`, which has no leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is *really* complicated, but it's not impossible — just likely many hundreds of lines of code before you're done.  I'm really not sure that this is the route you want to go — honestly, if you already know what format the date is in, you should probably just `parse()` it — but let's say for the sake of argument that you really *do* want to turn a date pattern like `YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` into a regular expression that can match dates in that format.

There are several steps in the solution:  You'll need to lexically analyze the pattern; transform the tokens into correct regex pieces in the current locale; and then mash them all together to make a regex you can use.  (Thankfully, you don't need to perform complex parsing on the date-pattern string; lexical analysis is good enough for this.)

Lexical analysis or *tokenization* is the act of breaking the input string into its component *tokens*, so that instead of an array of characters, it becomes a sequence of enumerated values or objects:  So for the previous example, you'd end up with an array or list like this: `[YYYY, Hyphen, mm, Hyphen, dd, Space, HH, Colon, mm, Colon, ss]`.  This kind of tokenization is often done with a big state machine, and you may be able to find some open-source code somewhere (part of the Android source code, maybe?) that already does it.  If not, you'll have to read each letter, count up how many of that letter there is, and choose an appropriate enum value to add to the growing list of tokens.

Once you have the tokenized sequence of elements, the next step is to transform each into a chunk of a regular expression that is valid for the current localization.  This is probably a giant `switch` statement inside a loop over the tokens, and thus would turn a `YYYY` enum value into the string piece `"[0-9]{4}"`, or the `mmm` enum value into a big chunk of regex string that matches all of the month names in the current locale (`"jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec"`).  This obviously involves you pulling all the data for the given locale, so that you can make regex chunks out of its words.

Finally, you can concatenate all of the regex bits together, wrapping each bit in parentheses to ensure precedence is correct, and then finally `Pattern.compile()` the whole string.  Don't forget to make it use a case-insensitive test.

If you don't know what locale you're in, you'll have to do this many times to produce many regexes for each possible locale, and then test the input against each one of them in turn.

This is a project-and-a-half, but it is something that *could* be built, if you really really really *need* it to work exactly like you described.

But again, if I were you, I'd stick with something that already exists:  If you already know what locale you're in (or even if you don't), the `parse()` method already not only does the lexical analysis and input-validation for you — and is not only already written! — but it also produces a usable date object, too!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Using `parse()` would require to have a String that only contains the date - which is unfortunaley not the case. And trying out each and every index of the String sounds bad performance and good practice-wise.

Answer (score 1):

I still think that parsing from each position in the string and seeing if it succeeds is simpler and easier than first generating a regular expression.

```
    Locale loc = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-AS");
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(loc);

    String mixed = "09/03/18Some data06/29/18Some other data04/27/18A third piece of data";
    // Check that the string starts with a date
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    LocalDate.from(dateFormatter.parse(mixed, pos));
    int dataStartIndex = pos.getIndex();
    System.out.println("Date: " + mixed.substring(0, dataStartIndex));
    int candidateDateStartIndex = dataStartIndex;
    while (candidateDateStartIndex < mixed.length()) {
        try {
            pos.setIndex(candidateDateStartIndex);
            LocalDate.from(dateFormatter.parse(mixed, pos));
            // Date found
            System.out.println("Data: " 
                    + mixed.substring(dataStartIndex, candidateDateStartIndex));
            dataStartIndex = pos.getIndex();
            System.out.println("Date: "
                    + mixed.substring(candidateDateStartIndex, dataStartIndex));
            candidateDateStartIndex = dataStartIndex;
        } catch (DateTimeException dte) {
            // No date here; try next
            candidateDateStartIndex++;
            pos.setErrorIndex(-1); // Clear error
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Data: " + mixed.substring(dataStartIndex, mixed.length()));
```

The output from this snippet was:

```
Date: 09/03/18
Data: Some data
Date: 06/29/18
Data: Some other data
Date: 04/27/18
Data: A third piece of data
```

If you’re happy with the accepted answer, please don’t let me take that away from you. Only please allow me to demonstrate the alternative to anyone reading along.

Exactly because I am presenting this for a broader audience, I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. If your data was originally written with a `DateFormat`, you may want to substitute that class into the above code. I trust you to do that in that case.